# How to enable object type button?

Tags: object, button, odoo

My python function returns an action url after which my button disables. OpenERP adds an attribute `disable="disable"` to my `button` . I don't want to `disable button`.

My code is

```
<button name="play_file" type="object" string="Play or download" />

 def play_file(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        res = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['file_name'], context=context)
        file_name = res[0]['file_name']
        return{
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'url':'ftp://test.claudion.com:123/'+file_name,
#            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Comment: It's Working for me! I have tried it locally. by giving home(localhost:8069) url!

Comment: Hello, Even i tested locally and it stays in enable state.

Comment: I have the same issue. The button will be disabled even if there is a raise error dialog window launched.

Comment: Hi Anuradha! If you have resolved the issue can you write the solution here? Thanks.